# Beyond compare in command line

Tags: beyondcompare4

I'm using Beyond Compare 4 from the command line to compare to files, which generates output report with differences. But, I'm not able to display the line numbers of differences. I used following script:

```
file-report layout:side-by-side options:display-mismatches output-to:%3 output-options:html-color,wrap-word %1 %2
```

Please suggest, how can I display the line number in report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **line-numbers** report option to include line numbers in a side-by-side report.

```
file-report layout:side-by-side options:display-mismatches,line-numbers output-to:%3 output-options:html-color,wrap-word %1 %2
```

See the **Scripting Reference** topic in [Beyond Compare 4's help file](http://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/) for a full description of all **file-report** options.